# Bound TextBox Value Lost Between Validating and Validated

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, .net-4.0

I have several controls on a windows form bound to an entity framework object (1 `DateTimePicker`, 1 `ComboBox`, and 2 `TextBoxes`).  The `DataSourceUpdateMode` is `OnValidation` (default), and the `AutoValidate` property of the form is set to `EnableAllowFocusChange`.  The binding for the `DateTimePicker` and `ComboxBox` work as expected.

However, when I enter something into the `TextBox`, the value disappears when I tab out.  Both `TextBox` controls are validated.  In the Validating event handler, I can see the value in the `Text` property of each `TextBox`.  However, by the time I get to the Validated event handler, the `Text` value is set back to an empty string.

EDIT:

After some experimentation, it seems to be related to the fact that I am binding the `TextBox` controls to properties that are of type `System.Nullable(Of Short)`.  I created a small test project with a class that contains a single, `System.Nullable(Of Short)` property.  When I bind a form with a single `TextBox` to that property, I experience the same issue.  However, if I change that property to type `Short`, it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3524691/43846 might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question Stuart Dunkeld linked to in the comments (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524691/43846), I discovered the `FormattingEnabled` property for the binding must be set to `true` when binding to a nullable type.