# C# winforms: Error when binding nullable type to other property (not Text)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, nullable

I've made a custom Textbox which displays a (nullable) decimal value as time (2.5 = 2:30). I've added a property "decimal? DecimalValue" to which I bind my datasource. This all works fine, except when I clear the Textbox, to make the value null.

It says "Object of type System.String cannot be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]".

What I saw is that base.OnValidating makes e.Cancel = True. So, somewhere underneath there is a check performed that causes this. I don't understand this behaviour though, because when I bind to property Text I can clear the Textbox without a problem and a null value is being saved.

Code of binding:

```
this.txtUrenDoorberekenen.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("DecimalValue", this.bsAutokraanOrderRegel, "Uren", true));
```

Custom property:

```
[Browsable(true), Bindable(true), Category("DSE"), DefaultValue(null), Description("De numerieke waarde")]
public decimal? DecimalValue
{
    get { return this.GeefNumeriek(this.Text); }
    set { this.Text = this.GeefTijd(value); }
}
```

this.GeefNumeriek return a decimal? (it converts the Text of Textbox to a nullable decimal).
this.GeefTijd(value) converts a nullable decimal to a string format.

```
    private decimal? GeefNumeriek(string waarde)
    {
        decimal? result = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(waarde)) {
            try {
                // voeg dubbele punt toe, indien deze ontbreekt
                if (waarde.Length == 1 && waarde.IndexOf(":") < 0) { waarde = waarde + ":00"; }
                if (waarde.Length == 2 && waarde.IndexOf(":") < 0) { waarde = waarde + ":00"; }
                if (waarde.Length >= 3 && waarde.IndexOf(":") < 0) { waarde = waarde.Substring(0, waarde.Length - 2) + ":" + waarde.Substring(waarde.Length - 2); }

                // Uren gedeelte
                result = Convert.ToDecimal(waarde.Substring(0, waarde.IndexOf(":")));

                // Minuten
                int minuten = Convert.ToInt16(waarde.Substring(waarde.IndexOf(":") + 1));
                // Minuten kan niet meer dan 60 zijn
                if (minuten > 60) { throw new Exception(DSETextResource.GeefText("Validatie_Numeriek_Ongeldig")); }

                result = result + ((decimal)minuten / (decimal)60);
            }
            catch {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3524691/1073107

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to databind a Winforms control to a nullable type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376361/best-way-to-databind-a-winforms-control-to-a-nullable-type)

Comment: No, it doesn't. In that question binding is on property Text, which does work. I want to bind to my own custom property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add some code to `Parse` event of `Binding` like this:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Text", yourObject, "DecimalProperty");
bind.Parse += (s,e) => {
  if((string)e.Value == "") e.Value = default(decimal?);
  else e.Value = decimal.Parse((string)e.Value);
};
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

**NOTE**: The code above suppose the string is always parsable to `decimal`.

Comment: I bind to another property, because Text is not parsable to decimal. There is no problem when binding to Text. Only when binding to another (custom) property and the value is null. It gives error both on loading null value in control as when clearing the textbox.

Comment: @RolandDeschain what's the type of **another custom property**? Looks like you don't want an answer. I've worked with `Binding` in winforms fairly much, almost the problems can be solved with `Parse` and `Format`.

Comment: It's decimal? (nullable decimal). And of course I want an answer. ;-)

Comment: @RolandDeschain it's so confusing, You should post your code to show how you bind your control, it's not `Text` but its type is `string` (I derived this from the exception message), so it's still applicable (just change the property name).

Comment: Code added. More needed?

Comment: @RolandDeschain what's the type of `Uren`? is it `string`?

Comment: "Uren" is the property of a Linq-to-SQL object. It's type is nullable decimal.

Comment: @RolandDeschain So both the properties are decimal or decimal?, How is the `Text` involved here? You said this `This all works fine, except when I clear the Textbox`? I guess your problem is this `this.GeefNumeriek` method. **Nothing's wrong with Binding here**.

Comment: @RolandDeschain you can show the method `GeefNumeriek` so that I can try to help or I think you could solve it yourself.

Comment: I've added the code of this.GeefNumeriek. I don't think this function is the problem. I've stepped to the code and when I clear the Textbox the DecimalValue return null (as intended). But when I step out of the Textbox it gives an error. See this image: http://i40.tinypic.com/akfkhs.jpg

Comment: @RolandDeschain you're right about the method, it should not throw such an exception. Your picture shows that the exception is shown by a `ErrorProvider`? You should disable that `ErrorProvider` and let code execution jump to the line throwing the exception. It helps you debug better. I doubt the problem **lies somewhere else** in your code. Looks like it's not easy to figure it out. In the worst case, I'll remove this answer.

Comment: It gives no error at all, but I cannot leave the textbox. base.OnValidating sets Cancel = true. Problem still there, but cannot figure out why/where.

Comment: I've come up with a solution that uses your answer.