# DataBinding Winforms Controls onto Nullable Types Locks Up GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, nullable

I have a Winforms application which allows the user to edit an array of objects. An object is selected by clicking on a row in a `DataGridView` and databound to various controls.
Recently, I wanted the object to be able to handle null values (for fields without data yet). This was accomplished using the `type?` convention.

```
private PDAFiles? pdafile;
public new PDAFiles? PDAFile
{
    get { return this.pdafile; }
    set { this.pdafile = value; }
}
```

Some additional handling (through custom formatting) allows fields to be read and wrote correctly. However, entering a value into a control locks up the GUI.

My code worked as intended before implementing nullable `type?` types. Looking at the variables in a debugger reveals that all values are read/written correctly. The program throws no exceptions. Most controls, including the close button, cannot be interacted with. The `DataGridView`, which selects an object to bind, can be interacted with, and selecting a different object/adding an object restores functionality.

DataBinding on ComboBox control:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("SelectedIndex", this.current_criteria, "PDAFile", true);
binding.Format += (sender, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        e.Value = e.Value == null ? -1 : e.Value;
    }
    catch { }
};
this.signalFileBox.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Removing these lines causes the problem to disappear. However, as the control is no longer databound, it does not load existing values from the object. A separate binding parses the user input. Removing the parser has no effect on locking up the GUI.
Setting `DataSource` from `DataGridView`:

```
this.selected_row_index = this.dataGridViewCriteria.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
MultiDataCollectionCriteria sources =
    new MultiDataCollectionCriteria
    (
        (from row in this.dataGridViewCriteria.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() 
        select this.data_criteria_source[row.Index] as DataCollectionCriteria).ToArray()
    );
this.current_criteria.DataSource = sources;
this.criteriaPanel.Enabled = true;
```

These lines function as intended; however, as noted, selecting a new row from the `DataGridView` unlocks the GUI.

I am looking to be able to bind controls to nullable types (with formatting) without causing the GUI to lock up. The behavior would be identical to a normal `DataBinding`, except that it can handle `type?` sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was posed here
[Best way to databind a Winforms control to a nullable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376361/best-way-to-databind-a-winforms-control-to-a-nullable-type)
The problem was solved by changing the Binding to `Binding binding = new Binding("SelectedIndex", this.current_criteria, "PDAFile", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never, -1);`
The `DataSourceUpdateMode.Never` was particularly important, as opposed to `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`, since I was manually parsing the input through separate means.